# Android Sherlock Action Bar - Styling SearchView, Share Intent Icon, homeAsUpIndicator

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I am using Sherlock Actionbar and want to change the icon thats displayed for the home as up enabled from Dark to a White color.

But my Theme needs Holo.Light. Is there any way i can set a custom icon for this via Styles ?

I am using the following Action Items in my Action Bar

main_activity.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Search"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_category"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_category"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Category"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_sort"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_sort"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Sort">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_sort_dist_nf"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
                android:title="Distance (Near-Far)"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_sort_dist_fn"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
                android:title="Distance (Far-Near)"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_sort_alpha_az"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_sort_az"
                android:title="Alpha (A-Z)"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_sort_alpha_za"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_sort_az"
                android:title="Alpha (Z-A)"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

activity_place.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:actionProviderClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.ShareActionProvider"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Search"/>

</menu>
```

I want to Style the Search View and the Search Icon. As Well as Share Intent Icon.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A custom theme like this.

```
<style name="Theme.mTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/image_with_whitecolorarrow</item>
    <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/image_with_whitecolorarrow</item>
</style>
```

For a custom searchView:

Define the menulayout in **menu** folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/searchIcon"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/search_icon_actionview"
        android:icon="@drawable/search_icon"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:title="Search"/>

</menu>
```

**searchIcon** you can use your custom icon. But must be of correct size of menuItems in an Actionbar.

define your custom searchView ie.., **search_icon_actionview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/search_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="Search icon"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/search_icon" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/search_editText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/search_image"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_white"
        android:hint="Search"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/text_dark_grey"
        android:textColorHint="@color/text_light_grey"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

the search icon and bell icon are custom images i made using photo shop.

**Activity Code:**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.searchIcon:

        mEtSearchbar.clearFocus();
        (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mEtSearchbar.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(
                        SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                        SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 0, 0, 0));
                mEtSearchbar.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(
                        SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                        SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,
                        0, 0, 0));
            }
        }, 100);

        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);

    mSearchbar = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.searchIcon);
    View actionview = mSearchbar.getActionView();
    mEtSearchbar = ((AutoCompleteTextView) actionview
            .findViewById(R.id.search_editText));
    final ImageView searchImage = ((ImageView) actionview
            .findViewById(R.id.search_image));
    searchImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            String s = mEtSearchbar.getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,
                    SearchActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("search_string", s);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    mEtSearchbar
            .setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                        KeyEvent event) {
                    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {

                        searchImage.performClick();
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: awesome. Thanks a lot! worked. Any idea how to style Search View ?

Comment: you mean the **actionLayout** for searchView?

Comment: yeah. where i can enter the text. Also i tried to assign a icon which on click expands - but its still taking the default icons.

Comment: i have set @drawable/ic_menu_search still it takes the default search icon. actually if u closely observe u can see the white icon at the background of the darker icon.

Comment: Then you can use the code i pasted. Just change the icons to your custom icons and have a custom actionLayout.

Comment: Yeah. That's a custom icon you can set in the menu.xml. I have added an image to my answer which is achieved using my code.

Comment: u havent used this android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView" is this needed ?

Comment: Thats the default actionLayout or actionViewClass, which appears once you click on the searchIcon from the menu. If you want to customize that, instead of actionViewClass use a actionLayout, with your fancy layout

Comment: thanks a lot. It worked. Now i have to got to try to see how i can expand it only when i click the icon and reattach the search view back to filtering the ListView Below :D thanks a lot. Wow i am loving it :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21520/discussion-between-harsha-m-v-and-archie-bpgc)